# Get statistical info (describe()-like) for groups of years in column

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

from a date(year)-like column I get this type of values:

```
+--------------------+------------+
|         CUSTOMER_ID|yearSelected|
+--------------------+------------+
|1                   |        2010|
|2                   |        1992|
|3                   |        1996|
|4                   |        1990|
|5                   |        1984|
+--------------------+------------+
```

Now I need to group them every five years (1990 to 1994: group 1, 1995 to 1996: group 2), and so on, and for every group, get info as if I was doing a df.describe()

What have I tried so far:

```
df8 = df4.groupBy('yearSelected')
stat_col = conf['by']

output = df8.agg(
    F.count(stat_col).alias("count"),
    F.mean(stat_col).alias("mean"),
    F.min(stat_col).cast(DecimalType(36,2)).alias("min"),
    F.max(stat_col).cast(DecimalType(36,2)).alias("max"),
    F.sum((F.col(stat_col) > 0).cast(DecimalType(36,2))).alias("greaterThan0"),
    F.sum((F.col(stat_col) == 0).cast(DoubleType())).alias("equalTo0"),
    F.sum((F.col(stat_col) < 0).cast(DecimalType(36,2))).alias("lesserThan0"),
).toPandas()
```

What this is missing is grouping by range of years, which is something I have not solved yet.

The other idea was using windows, but I am failing misserably:

```
windowSpecAgg  = Window.partitionBy("yearSelected").orderBy("yearSelected")
df5 = df4.withColumn("row",row_number().over(windowSpecAgg)) \
  .withColumn("avg", avg(col(conf['by'])).over(windowSpecAgg)) \
  .withColumn("sum", sum(col(conf['by'])).over(windowSpecAgg)) \
  .withColumn("min", min(col(conf['by'])).over(windowSpecAgg)) \
  .withColumn("max", max(col(conf['by'])).over(windowSpecAgg)) \
  .where(col("row")==1).select("yearSelected","avg","sum","min","max")
```

There are two reasons why I am failing, first is that I cannot properly finish this idea and put it into code, and the second, that every action I try to make (show(), describe(), count()) for THIS dataframe, and not for similar ones, I get:

```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2323.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 8 in stage 47.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 8.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 692, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last)

...
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
```

This is how I build the dataframe if it's at all useful (as I said I do this previous step in order to get the YEAR out of the column defined in the `conf[by]`:

```
funcDateTransf =  udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'), DateType())
df1 = df.withColumn('dateFormat', date_format(funcDateTransf(col(conf['by'])), 'MM-dd-yyy'))
df1 = df1.withColumn('date_in_dateFormat', 
               to_date(unix_timestamp(col('dateFormat'), 'MM-dd-yyyy').cast("timestamp")))
df3 = df1.select(conf['columnaJoin'],year('date_in_dateFormat').alias('yearSelected'))
#df3.show(5)

df4 = df1.join(df3, df1[conf['columnaJoin']] == df3[conf['columnaJoin']], 'inner')
```

I don't see why this particular way of creating a dataframe would give me trouble, and not when I do not create this extra column, but it is what I observe right now.

Comment: The udf `funcDateTransf` is throwing a Python error `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None`. Try replacing `udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'), DateType())` with `udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d') if x is not None else None, DateType())` and check if any error remains

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you are trying to ask (apologies, it's probably my fault). Are you struggling to group the individual years into the corresponding five-years range or struggling with calculating statistics similar to those used by `describe()` in Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood from your question, you are struggling with how to group the individual years into 5-years ranges. Let's imagine that your dataset is called `dataDF`. Now, in order to group your individual years by groups of 5-years, you could use:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dataDF.show()
+--------------------+------------+
|         CUSTOMER_ID|yearSelected|
+--------------------+------------+
|1                   |        2010|
|2                   |        1992|
|3                   |        1996|
|4                   |        1990|
|5                   |        1984|
+--------------------+------------+

dataDF.withColumn("new_column",
       F.when((F.col("yearSelected") >= 1980) & (F.col("yearSelected") <= 1984), "Group 1"), \
      .when((F.col("yearSelected") >= 1985) & (F.col("yearSelected") <= 1989), "Group 2"), \
      .when((F.col("yearSelected") >= 1990) & (F.col("yearSelected") <= 1994), "Group 3"), \
      .when((F.col("yearSelected") >= 1995) & (F.col("yearSelected") <= 1999), "Group 4"), \
      .when((F.col("yearSelected") >= 2000) & (F.col("yearSelected") <= 2004), "Group 5"), \
      .when((F.col("yearSelected") >= 2005) & (F.col("yearSelected") <= 2009), "Group 6"), \
      .when((F.col("yearSelected") >= 2010) & (F.col("yearSelected") <= 2014), "Group 7"), \
      .otherwise("N/A")).show()
```

The resulting dataset would be:

```
+--------------------+------------+-------------+
|         CUSTOMER_ID|yearSelected| new_column  |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+
|1                   |        2010|   Group 7   |
|2                   |        1992|   Group 3   |
|3                   |        1996|   Group 4   |
|4                   |        1990|   Group 3   |
|5                   |        1984|   Group 1   |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+
```

From here, you can group the data by `new_column` and obtain statistics as you have mentioned.

The disadvantage of this would be that you have to manually configure which ranges you want to choose. However, from your example, I guess you are not going too far back in time so this should work:)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot. Any way to do the new_column groups creation more automatically? Ranges are from 1900 to 2100 I believe, so it would not be huge but a bit on the big side. I was thinking using some struct but the syntax is not working so far